# jQuery, JSON, searching, etc

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, search

I've got a mass of values in a **JSON** file containing the names of venues and their contact information along with a description. I'd like to generate a table listing the contents of the JSON file on my page. I'm hoping to create a live search function that removes each entry that is no longer relevant with each`keyUp`detected.

**The JSON**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Aquarium Caf&eacute; Bar",
        "site": "http://www.aquariumcafebar.ca",
        "address": "2923 Masson 728-6116",
        "genre": "default"
    },‎
    {
        "name": "Ar&eacute;na Pierre &#8220;Pete&#8221; Morin",
        "site": "none",
        "address": "1925 St-Antoine 634-3471",
        "genre": "default",
    }
]
```

**The Proposed HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Aquarium Caf&eacute; Bar</td>
            <td>2923 Masson 728-6116</td>
            <td>http://www.aquariumcafebar.ca</td>
            <td>Rock</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've got a vague idea of how to grab the JSON from the venues.json file in jQuery, but I would really not know what to do with it once I have it to .append() a  containing all the info. I'm just looking for a bit of help with the syntax here!

Oh, and if you happen to have any bright ideas about how to update the table as the user searches, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Love,

BenjiBee

Comment: Small nitpick: that's not valid JSON syntax because the keys aren't quoted.

Comment: Why don't you attempt what you're doing and we can help you from then on?

Comment: @meder - Thanks for the input. I don't mean to come off as lazy, and am not looking for someone to do the work for me. I'm not sure about the best approach and am looking for direction and suggestions as to how to best go about this.

Comment: Then I recommend the `best-practices` tag... [oh wait](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [jQuery.tmpl](http://github.com/nje/jquery-tmpl) to create a table from the JSON data, using a template like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="VenueTemplate">
  <table id="VenueResults">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${address}</td>
        <td>${site}</td>
        <td>${genre}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

And this jQuery to render the template and inject it into a placeholder/container div named `Container`:

```
var yourJSONData;  // Assuming you've loaded this from wherever.

$('#VenueTemplate').tmpl(yourJSONData)
                   .appendTo('#Container');
```

Then use [the quickSearch plugin](http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/) to interactively filter that data.  It can be applied to the table (*after* rendering, of course) like this:

```
$('#SearchInputField').quicksearch('#VenueResults tbody tr');
```

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer, I wasn't expecting this much. You've just shaved off a good few days from this project. Rest easy knowing clean code is being utilized somewhere on the interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

It is a pretty simple task if you don't want to use a plugin. This assumes `jQuery 1.4` or later.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZBKSg/

jQuery

```
var $tbody = $('table > tbody');

   // Assumes the data is assigned to a variable "data"
for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var $tr = $('<tr />');
    $('<td/>',{text:data[i].name}).appendTo($tr);
    $('<td/>',{text:data[i].site}).appendTo($tr);
    $('<td/>',{text:data[i].address}).appendTo($tr);
    $('<td/>',{text:data[i].genre}).appendTo($tr);
    $tr.appendTo($tbody);
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

You could probably speed it up a little like this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZBKSg/1/

```
var $tbody = $('table > tbody');
var row = '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>'

for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var $tr = $(row);
    $tr.children(':first').text(data[i].name)
                .next().text(data[i].site)
                .next().text(data[i].address)
                .next().text(data[i].genre);
    $tr.appendTo($tbody);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to mark both replies as chosen answers. As far as I can tell both are just as efficient and fast. Thanks much for this code, it's extremely helpful and will save me hours of banging my head against the wall.